# Functions - Snowflake

Tags: function, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

-I'm trying to create a function that returns the date and the last time of that date, eg. 2022-09-29 23:59:59. I've tried this:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION date(Dt TIMESTAMP)
    RETURNS TIMESTAMP
    as
    $$select dateadd(second, -1, date_trunc('day', dateadd(day, 1, current_timestamp)))$$;
```

but got an error, does anyone have a clue?

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The return datatype doesn't match the actual. Make the return TIMESTAMP_LTZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should use parameter `DT` and function name should be renamed as [DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_date.html) already exists:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION date_(DT TIMESTAMP)
RETURNS TIMESTAMP
AS
$$select dateadd(second, -1, date_trunc('day', dateadd(day, 1, DT)))$$;

SELECT DATE_(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP());
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe function is an overkill? Lukasz already pointed out the issue, but if you must use a function, here's another way to define the date arithmetic

```
select current_timestamp::date + interval '86399 seconds'
```